# How to suppress rpm's notice-messages?

Tags: rpm

I need to query versions of a bunch of packages. Some of the packages may not be installed on the machine, in which case I'd like them to be *silently* ignored.

Unfortunately, `rpm -q` seems to mix the requested output with diagnostics together on `stdout` instead of sending the latter to `stderr` as one would expect. For example:

```
% rpm -q bash notinstalled
bash-4.2.46-19.el7.x86_64
package notinstalled is not installed
```

Using the `--quiet` flag suppresses *all* output, which is quite useless...

I know, I can filter the unwanted strings out with `grep`, but I'd like `rpm` to *not generate* them in the first place. Or, if it must generate them, send them to `stderr`, which I can then ignore, or straight to `/dev/null`.

Is it possible to avoid the post-processing with `grep` or some such?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RPM (for hysterical reasons) returns some statuses/errors in-band (i.e. on stdin, not stderr). So grep (or properly formed commands) are advised.

Another approach is to to loop over the CLI args, invoking one-by-one, checking the return code (but that is more coding than grep, ymmv).